# Finding the number of personal pronouns used in text using regrex with mixed case sensitive and insensitive modes

Tags: python, regex

I want to count the number of personal pronouns such as `I`, `we`, `my`, `ours` and `us` in a sentence using regex. I want it to ignore  `US` as it could be the name of a country.

My code is as follows

```
import re

pronounRegex = re.compile(r'I|we|my|ours|us',re.I)
pronouns = pronounRegex.findall(' I me  you We and all of us make this team tweek, he is from US')
print(pronouns)
```

which prints

```
['I', 'We', 'us', 'i', 'we', 'i', 'US']
```

It is reading the "i" from "this" and "we" from "tweek". I'm not sure how to ignore those cases.

Comment: This will also match any word that contains a fragment in your regex. e.g. bus will match "us", will will match "i", wednesday will match we

Comment: You can still use `re.I` and use a shorter regex if you use inline modifier groups. There is no need to repeat `\b` with every alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You matched `US` because your regex has a `us` alternative and the `re.I` flag enables case insensitive search.

You get partial matches inside words because your regex is context-unaware, not "anchored" in any way. If you need to match words, use word boundaries. You do not need to put them with every alternative though, you can use a *grouping* construct and put `\b` only on both ends of the group.

You can use

```py
pronounRegex = re.compile(r'\b(I|we|my|ours|(?-i:us))\b',re.I)
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (immediately on the left, there can be start of string position, or a non-word char)
- `(` - start of a capturing group with ID 1:

  - `I|we|my|ours` - one of the `I`, `we`, `my`, `ours` words
- `|` - or

  - `(?-i:us)` - *inline modifier group* where matching is CASE SENSITIVE, and this only matches `us` (not `US`)
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - as the previous char was a word char, the next position is either end of string, or there is a non-word char following.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oYWK4H):

```py
import re
pronounRegex = re.compile(r'\b(I|we|my|ours|(?-i:us))\b',re.I)
pronouns = pronounRegex.findall(' I me  you We and all of us make this team tweek, he is from US')
print(pronouns)
# => ['I', 'We', 'us']
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVnMlz/1) (note PCRE option is selected, as there is a bug with the Python option at regex101).

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent `re` from matching words `this`, `tweek`, you can use word boundaries. Add `\b` to the front and back of each regex items in between the operator, `|`

Like this,

```py
r'\bI\b|\bwe\b|\bmy\b|\bours\b|\bus\b'
```

Now, to prevent the matching of `US` you need to explicitly specify the possible forms of the verbs. Such as, the pronoun `we` can be written as `We` or `we` itself but not `wE`.

So, remake your regex like this,

```py
pronounRegex = re.compile(r'\bI\b|\bwe\b|\bWe\b|\bmy\b|\bMy\b|\bours\b|\bus\b')
pronounRegex.findall(' I me  you We and all of us make this team tweek, he is from US')
```

Also, notice that the pronouns `ours` and `us` are not provided in the capitalized form. As those pronouns can never be present at the starting of a sentence (that is, *possessive form*).

Answer (score 1):

Add word boundaries, `\b`, to the front and back of the regex items in between the operator, `|`

```
r'\bI\b|\bwe\b|\bmy\b|\bours\b|\bus\b'
```

Comment: this works, except that it is still counting "US"

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the lowercase 'i' folowing snippet can be used

```
pronounRegex = re.compile(r'\b((?-i:I)|we|my|ours|(?-i:us))\b', re.I)
pronouns = pronounRegex.findall(file_to_analyse)
print(pronouns)
pronoun_count = len(pronouns)
print(pronoun_count)
```